# How to pass data of one label(mainStoryBoard) to another label(of second storyboard)

Tags: swift, label, swift4, uistoryboard

I have a label1 in a view controller of main.storyboard 
i have another label2 in view controller of storyboard named Second.storyboard
how can I pass data from one storyboard to another all solutions I can find are about passing data within the same storyboard.Help me with my question.

Comment: are you pushing or presenting to another view controller ?

Comment: @Vicky_Vignesh im Pushing

Comment: Have you checked my answer ?

Comment: yes vicky its working

Comment: Awesome! Upvote or Do accept if the answer helped :)

Answer (score 0):

make a Global variable in Second View Controller

```
var labelText = ""
```

While Pushing to secondViewController from First Controller

```
        let secondVC = secondViewController()
        secondVC.labelText = label.text // Pass label text from first VC 
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: @MuhammadBilal Awesome! Upvote or Do accept if the answer helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Create the instance of `Storyboard` with the relevant `name` while creating the instance of `SecondViewController` in `FirsViewController`, i.e

```
class FirsViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

    func pushVC2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard-2", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController { //here....
            controller.str = "Your_Text_Here"
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Your `SecondViewController` looks like,

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    var str: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.label2.text = str
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. Do accept (tick on left) and upvote if the answer helped. Happy coding 